# Duda con postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, data, postgresql-12

He realizado este ejercicio del cual no estoy seguro de haberlo hecho correctamente, la respuesta que obtengo es como debería ser pero dudo verdaderamente de que sea la información correcta, así que si alguien pudiera revisar mi código y realizar alguna sugerencia será agradecido.

Tengo una base de datos cuyo esquema es el siguiente: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que debo averiguar es ¿Cuáles son las 3 películas más comunes que los clientes alquilan como su primer alquiler?
Mi razonamiento fue el siguiente:
primero cruzar las peliculas con los id de cada cliente ordenado por fecha de alquiler
con ello en segundo lugar seleccionar la primer película de cada cliente y en tercer lugar contar la cantidad de clientes por cada pelicula usando COUNT(id_customer) WHERE a.title = b.title FROM lo obtenido anteriormente JOIN con sigo mismo.
El razonamiento creo que está bien pero no se el código. Adjunto también el resultado obtenido

```
WITH movies_bycustomer AS (SELECT title,
customer_id, DATE(rental_date) date_rental
FROM customer 
INNER JOIN rental USING (customer_id)
INNER JOIN inventory USING (inventory_id)
INNER JOIN film USING (film_id)
GROUP BY customer_id, title, date_rental
ORDER BY date_rental),
first_movie_percustomer AS(

SELECT 
    customer_id,
    FIRST_VALUE(title) 
    OVER(
    PARTITION BY customer_id
        ORDER BY date_rental
        RANGE BETWEEN 
            UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 
            UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
    ) first_movie_bycustomer
FROM 
    movies_bycustomer
GROUP BY customer_id, title, date_rental)
    
SELECT COUNT(a.customer_id), a.first_movie_bycustomer
FROM first_movie_percustomer a JOIN first_movie_percustomer b USING (customer_id)
WHERE a.first_movie_bycustomer = b.first_movie_bycustomer
GROUP BY a.first_movie_bycustomer
ORDER BY COUNT(a.customer_id) DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Resultado obtenido:

[image: resultado obtenido]

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

En tu planteamiento estás usando correctamente una función window para obtener el título de la película con la menor fecha por cada usuario, pero estás repitiendo registros porque no se puede agrupar por una función window y no estás limitando los resultados sino, al revés, aumentándolos. Me explico

Supongamos una tabla simplificada `rentals_simple`

| customer_id | date_rental | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-03-01 | Rápido y Furioso |
| 1 | 2021-03-16 | Avengers |
| 1 | 2021-03-22 | Star Wars |
| 2 | 2021-03-01 | Karate Kid |
| 2 | 2021-03-22 | Avengers |
| 3 | 2021-01-01 | Karate Kid |
| 3 | 2021-02-18 | Matrix |

La consulta

```
 SELECT customer_id, FIRST_VALUE(title) as first_title 
        OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY rental_date)
 FROM rentals_simple
 GROUP BY customer_id, title, date_rental
```

mostraría

| customer_id | first_title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Rápido y Furioso |
| 1 | Rápido y Furioso |
| 1 | Rápido y Furioso |
| 2 | Karate Kid |
| 2 | Karate Kid |
| 3 | Karate Kid |
| 3 | Karate Kid |

Al hacer join con sí misma

```
WITH first_movie_percustomer AS (
     SELECT customer_id, FIRST_VALUE(title) as first_title 
            OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY rental_date)
     FROM rentals_simple
     GROUP BY customer_id, title, date_rental
)
  SELECT count(f1.customer_id) as conteo, f1.first_title
    FROM first_movie_percustomer f1 JOIN first_movie_percustomer f2 using (customer_id)
    WHERE f1.first_title=f2.first_title
    GROUP BY f1.first_title
```

Obtendrás:

| conteo | first_title |
| --- | --- |
| 9 | Rápido y Furioso |
| 8 | Karate Kid |

Lo cual obviamente es incorrecto no sólo en cantidades sino en el orden presentado.

Para empezar, la cláusula group by en la definición de `first_movie_percustomer` no tiene ningún efecto, dado que sólo agruparía registros de un mismo cliente que compartan título y fecha. El esquema relacional no permite que se junten en un mismo rental más de una película, por lo que nunca habrá dos registros en esa consulta que tengan la misma fecha.

---

#### Soluciones posibles pero subóptimas

La fecha del primer arriendo de cada cliente puede obtenerse como

```
SELECT customer_id, min(rental_date) as rental_date 
FROM rental
GROUP BY customer_id
```

por lo que el inventory_id del primer arriendo es

```
WITH first_rental_dates as (
    SELECT customer_id, min(rental_date) as rental_date 
    FROM rental
    GROUP BY customer_id
)
SELECT inventory_id 
   FROM rentals 
   JOIN first_rental_dates USING (customer_id, rental_date)
```

El inventory_id define una relación unívoca con un film_id, así que el total de veces en que cada película ha sido la primera de un cliente se obtiene de:

```
WITH first_rental_dates as (
   SELECT customer_id, min(rental_date) as rental_date 
    FROM rental
    GROUP BY customer_id
),
first_inventories AS (
  SELECT inventory_id 
   FROM rentals 
   JOIN first_rental_dates USING (customer_id, rental_date)
)
SELECT film_id, title, count(*)
 FROM first_inventories
 JOIN inventory USING (inventory_id)
 JOIN film USING (film_id)
```

Alternativamente se puede hacer con una window function, pero igual requieres la misma cantidad de pasos. El segundo paso (que en tu caso omitiste) se queda con una sola fila

```
WITH first_rental_ids as (
   SELECT customer_id, first_value(rental_id) as first_rental 
    FROM rental
    GROUP BY customer_id
),
first_inventories AS (
  SELECT inventory_id 
   FROM rentals 
   WHERE exists (SELECT 1 FROM first_rental_ids WHERE first_rental=rental_id)
)
SELECT film_id, title, count(*)
 FROM first_inventories
 JOIN inventory USING (inventory_id)
 JOIN film USING (film_id)
```

---

#### La solución elegante

Para esto en realidad debiera usarse [DISTINCT ON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) como consta en la documentación de postgres:

> SELECT DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal

Por lo que

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ON (customer_id) 
     customer_id, 
     title
 FROM rental
 JOIN inventory USING (inventory_id)
 JOIN film USING (film_id)
 ORDER BY customer_id, rental_date
```

reemplazaría a las primeras dos subqueries,.

Comment: Espectacular!! Muchas gracias entonces debería usar  la ultima solución brindada como una subquery llamada first_movie_customer seguida de    ```SELECT film_id, title, count(*)
 FROM first_movie_customer
 JOIN inventory USING (inventory_id)
 JOIN film USING (film_id) ``` es correcto @ffflabs ?

Comment: Es correcto. Pero debieras probarlo con data